# Amazon Web Service for Alexa

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-internet

AWS (Amazon Web Service) provides an API for submitting HTTP requests to Alexa.

This API is called Alexa Web Information Service.

I submit an HTTP request with `&Action=UrlInfo` and `&ResponseGroup=UsageStats`.

I then receive an XML within the HTTP response.

Here is the part in the XML which is relevant to my question:

```
<aws:PageViews>
    <aws:PerMillion>
        <aws:Value>12,345</aws:Value>
        <aws:Delta>+0.67%</aws:Delta>
    </aws:PerMillion>
    <aws:Rank>
        <aws:Value>1</aws:Value>
        <aws:Delta>0</aws:Delta>
    </aws:Rank>
    <aws:PerUser>
        <aws:Value>12.34</aws:Value>
        <aws:Delta>-0.56%</aws:Delta>
    </aws:PerUser>
</aws:PageViews>
```

The documentation for the API is at **http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AlexaWebInfoService/latest/**.

A description for the specific parameters that I am using in my HTTP request, can be found under **API Reference** / **Actions** / **UrlInfo**, but I have not been able to find any details on any of the above tags.

**Does anyone happen to know the exact meaning of each of these tags? :**

- PerMillion / Value
- PerMillion / Delta
- Rank / Value
- Rank / Delta
- PerUser / Value
- PerUser / Delta

Thanks

Comment: this is something I'm looking for years but apparently they have a terrible api documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding aws:PerMillion

> The PageViews PerMillion stat shows "out of every million pageviews
>   made by all users on the Internet today how many pageviews are made on
>   this site?" The daily pageviews number is then averaged over the
>   specified time period.
>
> https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=578614

and aws:PerUser

> it is "per million pageviews on the internet"
>
> https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=265890

Answer (score 0):

I've annotated a sample result with my understanding of the return values based on Treton's answer:

```xml
 <aws:TopSites>
  <!-- Country in which the sites in this result have been grouped. -->
  <aws:Country>
    <aws:CountryName>Australia</aws:CountryName>
    <aws:CountryCode>AU</aws:CountryCode>
    <!-- Total number of sites Alexa is tracking in this country -->
    <aws:TotalSites>22052</aws:TotalSites>
    <!-- List of sites in result. -->
    <aws:Sites>
      <aws:Site>
        <aws:DataUrl>google.com</aws:DataUrl>
        <aws:Country>
          <!-- Rank within country (eg 10 = 10th most popular site in country). -->
          <aws:Rank>1</aws:Rank>
          <!-- -->
          <aws:Reach>
            <!--
            Out of every million users on the internet today, how many visited
            this site?
            @see https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=578614
            -->
            <aws:PerMillion>801700</aws:PerMillion>
          </aws:Reach>
          <aws:PageViews>
            <!--
            Out of every million pageviews by all users on the internet
            today, how many were made to this site?
            -->
            <aws:PerMillion>267200</aws:PerMillion>
            <!--
            What is the average (mean) number of pageviews to this site, per
            user, per day?
            -->
            <aws:PerUser>14.94</aws:PerUser>
          </aws:PageViews>
        </aws:Country>
        <!-- Rank within whole world.  -->
        <aws:Global>
          <aws:Rank>1</aws:Rank>
        </aws:Global>
      </aws:Site>
    </aws:Sites>
  </aws:Country>
</aws:TopSites>
```